Performance difference between Chrome and Firefox: Object.assign, spread, adding properties in loop
I'm currently looking into performance of creating objects in a data container that are initialized with a known list of properties that should intially be all null.
I was testing different approaches:

the code we had that iterates over the list of properties and adds
each to an object that was initialized empty

function createEmptyRow() {
  const result = {};
  props.forEach(prop => result[prop] = null);
  return result;
}


Creating one template empty object with createEmptyRow and copying it with spread
operator { ... }

function copyEmptyRow() {
  return { ...emptyObj }
}


Creating one template empty object with createEmptyRow and copying it with Object.assign

function copyEmptyRowAssign() {
  return Object.assign({}, emptyObj);
}

Testing this in a TS Playground showed that spread operator and Object.assign were fastest, but our code got slower actually when I did the change. I noticed that there was a big difference between Chrome (what I used to test our code) and Firefox (used to test on TS Playground).
I ended up creating a MeasureThat benchmark that did confirm this.
Differences are significant, where the performance of our original code is comparable, the other two are so much slower on Chrome that I can't explain it. Anyone an idea what is happening here?
Timings from my machine:

Chrome results

Firefox results
